# What is wrong with my code in Python Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

When I run the code and input "1" or "2" it gives me the response

> Sorry, we didn't understand your selection.

How do I fix this so that it gives me the correct answer?

I've Tried making "1" and "2" a string.

```
def cs_service_bot():
    # Replace `pass` with your code
    response = input("Hello! Welcome to the DNS Cable Company's Service Portal. Are you a new or existing customer? \n [1] New Customer \n [2] Existing Customer \n Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:")
    if response == "1":
        return new_customer()
    elif response == "2":
        return existing_customer()
    else:
        print("Sorry, we didn't understand your selection.")
        return cs_service_bot()

cs_service_bot()
```

No error messages, It won't give me the answer I am looking for which is either one of these functions: `new_customer()` or `existing_customer()`

Comment: python2 or python3? Also input `1` instead of `"1"`

Comment: Check `type` of  response. You will get the answer.

Comment: Have you tried making `1` and `2` *not* a string? (Like, `if response == 1:`)

Comment: your code is working fine for me in both terminal and jupyter

Comment: @Jeril Because you are using python 3. Python 2 is having `input` and `raw_input` concepts

Comment: I have a similar question here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540892/game-of-chance-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 0):

Try by converting `response` in to **string** and then compare.

```
def cs_service_bot():
    # Replace `pass` with your code
    response = input("Hello! Welcome to the DNS Cable Company's Service Portal. Are you a new or existing customer? \n [1] New Customer \n [2] Existing Customer \n Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:")
    if str(response) == "1":
        return new_customer()
    elif str(response) == "2":
        return existing_customer()
    else:
        print("Sorry, we didn't understand your selection.")
        return cs_service_bot()

cs_service_bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python2 ,input is returning integer,
so you need do to:

```
response = input("Hello! Welcome to the DNS Cable Company's Service Portal. Are you a new or existing customer? \n [1] New Customer \n [2] Existing Customer \n Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:")
if response == 1:
    return new_customer()
```

or:

```
response = input("Hello! Welcome to the DNS Cable Company's Service Portal. Are you a new or existing customer? \n [1] New Customer \n [2] Existing Customer \n Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:")
if str(response) == "1":
    return new_customer()
```

Examples:

```
Python 2.x
s1 = raw_input("Enter raw_input to test raw_input() function: ")
>> 3
print (type(s1))  <type 'str'>
s11 = raw_input("Enter raw_input to test raw_input() function: ")
>> a
print (type(s11))  <type 'str'>


s2 = input("Enter input to test input() function: ")
>> 3 
print (type(s2))  <type 'int'>
s22 = input("Enter input to test input() function: ")
>> a
print (type(s22))  <type 'str'>


Python 3.x
s3 = input("Enter input to test input() function: ")
>> 1
print (type(s3))  <type 'str'>
s33 = input("Enter input to test input() function: ")
>> a
print (type(s33))  <type 'str'>
```

EDIT:

```
def new_customer():
    print ("new_customer")

def existing_customer():
    print ("existing_customer")

def cs_service_bot():
    # Replace `pass` with your code
    response = input("Hello! Welcome to the DNS Cable Company's Service Portal. Are you a new or existing customer? \n [1] New Customer \n [2] Existing Customer \n Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:")
    if response == "1":
        return new_customer()
    elif response == "2":
        return existing_customer()
    else:
        print("Sorry, we didn't understand your selection.")
        return cs_service_bot()

cs_service_bot()
```

output:

```
Hello! Welcome to the DNS Cable Company's Service Portal. Are you a new or existing customer? 
 [1] New Customer 
 [2] Existing Customer 
 Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:1
new_customer
```

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: what you are entering like input 1 with quotation marks,like "1"? @DaRidg

Comment: ok thx that worked, I also have a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540892/game-of-chance-in-python-3-x