# Game of Chance in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this problem in my python code which is a coinflip game, the problem is that when It asks, "Heads or Tails?" and I just say 1 or Heads(same for 2 and Tails) without quotation marks and with quotation marks, it does not give me an answer that I am looking for.

I've Tried using quotation marks in my answer which didn't seem to work either.

```py
import random

money = 100

#Write your game of chance functions here
def coin_flip(choice, bet):
   choice = input("Heads or Tails?")
   coinnum = random.randint(1, 2)
   if coinnum == 1:
      return 1
   elif coinnum == 2:
      return 2
   win = bet*2
   if choice == "Heads" or "1":
       return 1
   elif choice == "Tails" or "2":
      return 2
   if choice == coinnum:
      print("Well done! You have won " + str(win) + " Dollars!")
   elif choice != coinnum:
      print("Sorry, you lost " + str(bet) + " Dollars!")

coin_flip("Heads", 100)
```

The expected output was either "Well done! You have won 200 Dollars!" or "Sorry, you lost 100 Dollars!"

Comment: Then do not return before printing.

Comment: @DaRidg you need to start code with `\`\`\`` and end it with `\`\`\``. Then you can type normal code in between. More infos here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Regarding `if choice == "Heads" or "1":`, which doesn't do what you probably think it does, a good resource to read would be [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note here is that your usage of `return` seems to be wrong. Please look up tutorials about how to write a function and how to use `return`.

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```py
import random

money = 100

#Write your game of chance functions here
def coin_flip(choice, bet):
   choice = input("Heads or Tails? ")
   coinnum = random.randint(1, 2)
   win = bet*2

   if choice == "Heads" or choice == "1":
      choicenum = 1
   elif choice == "Tails" or choice == "2":
      choicenum = 2
   else:
      raise ValueError("Invalid choice: " + choice)

   if choicenum == coinnum:
      print("Well done! You have won " + str(win) + " Dollars!")
   else:
      print("Sorry, you lost " + str(bet) + " Dollars!")

coin_flip("Heads", 100)
```

Now, lets go through the mistakes I found in your code:

- `return` was totally out of place, I wasn't sure what you were intending here.
- `if choice == "Heads" or "1"` is invalid, `"1"` always evaluates to `true`. Correct is: `if choice == "Heads" or choice == "1":`
- `elif choice != coinnum:` is unnecessary, if it doesn't run into `if choice == coinnum:` a simple `else:` would suffice.

Comment: for some reason in vscode, it says "IndentationError: unexpected indent" with "else:"

Comment: Can't help you with that, I think you are doing something wrong there :/ https://onlinegdb.com/B1R60epAE

Comment: sorry i changed the comment

Comment: I still think you are doing something wrong ... It works flawlessly for me. Be sure to copy all the indentation, python indentation is not just for looks

Comment: it seems to work on any online python runner but not in vscode

Comment: Also, while it looks the same, *tab* and *multiple spaces* are **not** the same thing in python. Please make sure you don't have some of those mixed up.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1
 /Users/myname/Documents/Coding/Python/chancegames.py      
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: That again is a different error than the "IndentationError" you told us earlier. Make up your mind :P

Comment: Yeah sorry the original error came up again saying syntax error

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something that we can really fix in the comment section ... This goes more in the direction of *how to use your ide* and is therefore off-topic. Maybe ask someone who can come over and explain more interactively, or some remote desktop session or something?

Comment: Sorry about all this confusion, I fixed it(I restarted vscode). Thx for the help :)